# mobile: ul content disappears after scrolling

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile, browser

I am working on a navigation bar for my companies website atm.
We are using wordpress for basic stuff, the navigation bar has to be manually coded in css and html.
Here you have the site which is currently under work:
*link not avaiable*
On desktop the site works just fine, but on mobile we got a little problem.

When clicking on one of the li-elements the site scrolls down to the specific product. Doing this on a mobile browser works until you scroll by yourself and click on another li-element. Then the content of the ul will disappear but the li-elements are still clickable. Scrolling again will let the elements appear.

Here's the code snippet of the navigation bar:

```css
.kategorien{
 position: fixed;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 background-color: #888;
 text-decoration: none;
 min-width: 100%;
 width: 18%; 
 height: 86px; 
 text-align: center; 
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 &::-webkit-scrollbar {
 }
}

.kategorien .link{
 background-size: 100px, 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link1{
 background: url(https://standard.kuebrich.com/kuebrich-2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Icon_mechatronische-Bauteile.png);
}
.link2{
 background: url(https://standard.kuebrich.com/kuebrich-2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Icon_Tuer.png);
}
.link3 {
 background: url(https://standard.kuebrich.com/kuebrich-2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Schloss-e1503557362607.png);
}
.link4 {
 background: url(https://standard.kuebrich.com/kuebrich-2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Icon_sitz.png);
}

.link5 {
 background: url(https://standard.kuebrich.com/kuebrich-2016/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/RSG.png);
}

.kategorien li {
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.kategorien li a{
 display: block;
 color: white;
 padding-top: 50px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.kategorien a:hover{
 color: #6bf;
}
```

```html
<ul class="entry-content kategorien">
<li><a class="link link1" href="#tueren">Türen</a></li>
<li><a class="link link2" href="#fenster">Fenster</a></li>
<li><a class="link link3" href="#schloss">Schloss</a></li>
<li><a class="link link4" href="#sitz">Sitz</a></li>
<li><a class="link link5" href="#rsg">RSG</a></li>
<li><a class="link link4" href="#sitz">Sitz</a></li>
<li><a class="link link2" href="#fenster">Fenster</a></li>
<li><a class="link link3" href="#schloss">Schloss</a></li>
<li><a class="link link4" href="#sitz">Sitz</a></li>
<li><a class="link link2" href="#fenster">Fenster</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please let me know if there is anything I can add to this code to solve this problem or you need further information.
FYI: The code has to be done in css and html only.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. Could you tell me which device you are using and which browser?

Comment: Of course. I am using a iPhone 5s(iOS 10.3.1) with Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
@media (max-width: 980px) {
  .et_fixed_nav #top-header {
     position: fixed !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now you can use this.

Comment: FYI: You are styling the top-menu/top-header, but that isn't the source of my problem. It is in .kategorien and in the navigation bar which you can see in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media all and(max-width: 980px) {
  .et_fixed_nav #top-header {
     position: fixed !important;
  }
#top-menu {
    display: block !important;
 }
}
```

This should solve your problem, but not good solution.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem. FYI: You are styling the top-menu/top-header, but that isn't the source of my problem. It is in .kategorien and in the navigation bar which you can see in the code snippet.

Comment: @SeriousSimon : where are you putting the css i have given you? I have edited my answer lil bit. please check now.

Comment: I am putting it right after the <style>-tag. New version from you still doesnt work ...